# Как подружить программу с другой?

Tags: java, android

Я начинающий ̶х̶а̶к̶е̶р разработчик android (изучаю Java) и в моей голове возникла идея создать приложение.

Краткое описание:
1.) В приложение можно загрузить .mp3 файл
2.) Файл отправляется на сервер, где установлена DAW (К примеру: FL Studio)
3.) Файл загружается в программу FL Studio, обрабатывается, и рендерится в новый файл
4.) В приложение отправляется ссылка на скачивание этого файла

Даже не знаю как спросить это у гугла...
Подскажите что изучать, чтобы я мог это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну это зависит от того как именно вы хотите чтоб программы взаимодействовали.

Если это какой-то удаленный сервер, то вам необходимо API которое позволит работать с этим сервером.

Если же это какое-то приложение которое находится на вашем устройстве, то для этого используется Content Provider